# Algebra generated by a collection of subset of a set

Tags: measure-theory

If I define algebra generated by a subset $S$ of power set of $X$ as intersection of all algebras containing $S$. Then is it true: every element in algebra generated by $S$ can be written as finite union of elements of $S$ or complements of elements of $S$.

Where algebra on $X$ is subset of power set of $X$ with three properties, which I think I don't need to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false.

Let $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $S = \{A, B\}$, where $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$. Then $A \cap B = \{2\}$ is in the algebra generated by $S$, but cannot be written as a union of sets among $A = \{1, 2\}$, $B = \{2, 3\}$, $A^c = \{3\}$ and $B^c = \{1\}$.